# Marshmallow with TGUID and Oracle

Tags: spring4d

[image]I'm mapping my table with a TGuid type ID, the select works fine, but the inserts return an error stating that the TGuid type fields are not supported. How this mapping should be performed so that the includes and updates work between Marshmallow and the database (Oracle).

Existe algum documento mais aprofundado sobre o Marshmallow que possa consultar?

Is there any data type other than TGuid to use? I've tried using TBytes, TVarByte and other similar types but without success.